# Do objects in category form a set?

Tags: category-theory

I want to implement a notion of a category, monoidal category and braided monoidal category in haskell. And I'm not sure if `[a]` or `Data.Set` a is a correct notion for representing an objects in a category.

Comment: Not in general. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_category#Small_and_large_categories).

Comment: @Andrew: There are the class “Category” in “base” and the classes “Monoidal”, “Braided” in “category-extras”. Maybe this is not what you need, as I do not understand “implementing”. Haskell is for computing, not for reasoning.

Comment: here is nice implementation by Edward Kmett http://hackage.haskell.org/package/categories

Comment: btw, it's possible to define categories without notion of object, with arrows only

Comment: How to implement the notion of a category in Haskell depends on whether you want categories to be values, types, or something else entirely. If a category is a value, as you seem to be wanting, there's no good answer to your question, but I think it may make more sense to make the category be an entire type, rather than just a list or set. That said, I think this is really more of a Haskell question than a math question; I'd suggest posting it on stackoverflow.com for better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most categories do not have a set of objects.  When this does happen, you have what is called a *small* category.  Despite this, many categories have what is known as a *small skeleton*, meaning that the category of objects up to isomorphism is small.  Such a category is said to be *essentially small*, and examples of such categories include finite dimensional $k$-vector spaces (for some field $k$) and finite sets.

Comment: “essentially small” or *svelte*